# Prevent conditional checking on Hash to create Key

Tags: ruby

Whenever I run a conditional checking on Hash to see if a key doesn't have any value, it creates that key

```
x = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []}
puts x
>>>>{}


if x[0] == []
    puts "Ok"
end

>>>>Ok

puts x
>>>> {0=>[]}
```

How do I prevent this?

Comment: What do you want as output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`has_key?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-has_key-3F) method:

```
x = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }

x.has_key?(0)
#=> false
x
#=> {}
```

Saying that you could change your condition to:

```
puts "Ok" if x.has_key?(0) && x[0] == []
```

That means you will only check the value for `x[0]` if you alreday know that the key exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []}
```

if you create hash like this, it will set a new default object each time.

for example:

```
x = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = 0}

x[0]
=> 0
x
=> {0=>0}

x = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] =  "a" }
=> {}

x[0]
=> "a"
x
=> {0=>"a"}
```

so you should know what default hash value do you want.